# mathematica printing with multiple indices

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What do I need to do to make Pa[p] an ASN[P] to come out as numeric values.
Abreviated code is given below.  roots, PA2[p] and ANS2[p] are created
using an i index.

MMA CODE:  ****************

```
Clear[x, y, p];
x := BinomialDistribution[n1, p];
y := BinomialDistribution[n2, p];

Pa[p_] := CDF[x, c1] + Sum[PDF[x, j]*CDF[y, c2 - j], {j, c1 + 1, c2}];
Print[TableForm[Table[{p, Pa[p]}, {p, .01, .1, .01}],
             TableHeadings -> {None, {"p", "Pa[p]"}}]];
ASN[p_] := n1*1 + n2* CDF[x, c2] - CDF[x, c1];   
Print[TableForm[Table[{p, ASN[p]}, {p, .01, .1, .01}],
             TableHeadings -> {None, {"p", "ASN[p]"}}]];

p = {.01, .02, .03, .04, .05, .06, .07, .08, .09, .1};
Print[TableForm[
Table[ {r2[[i]], p[[i]], Pa[[i]], ASN[[i]], Pa2[[i]],ASN2[[i]] }, 
      {i, 1,10,1}],               
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"roots", "p", "Pa[p]","ASN[p]","PA2[p]","ASN2[p]"} } ]];
```

MMA OUTPUT:  *****************

```
p   Pa[p]
0.01    0.980277
0.02    0.817478
0.03    0.555413
0.04    0.327922
0.05    0.177956
0.06    0.0916007
0.07    0.0453877
0.08    0.0217882
0.09    0.0101644
0.1 0.00461704

p   ASN[p]
0.01    178.866
0.02    176.136
0.03    167.438
0.04    153.427
0.05    137.505
0.06    122.884
0.07    111.274
0.08    102.986
0.09    97.5368
 0.1    94.1847

roots           p             Pa[p]          ASN[p]             PA2[p]          ASN2[p]
1.17508      0.01   Pa$1660[[1]]    ASN$1660[[1]]   0.977398        64.4721
0.472821     0.02   Pa$1660[[2]]    ASN$1660[[2]]   0.840606             84.1587
0.000638883  0.03   Pa$1660[[3]]    ASN$1660[[3]]   0.583404        89.3915
```

-0.3770350    .04    Pa$1660[[4]]    ASN$1660[[4]]   0.340761             79.3716
    -0.7039350   .05    Pa$1660[[5]]    ASN$1660[[5]]   0.185355             65.0975
     -1.            0.06    Pa$1660[[6]]    ASN$1660[[6]]   0.1         52.7007
   -1.27609      0.07   Pa$1660[[7]]    ASN$1660[[7]]   0.0547126   43.2261
   -1.5388       0.08   Pa$1660[[8]]    ASN$1660[[8]]   0.0304681   36.1651
   -1.79248      0.09   Pa$1660[[9]]    ASN$1660[[9]]   0.017227              30.8583
   -2.04012      0.1    Pa$1660[[10]]   ASN$1660[[10]]  0.00985218  26.7938

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to evaluate a list position `[[]]` of a function `[]`, i.e. when you call `Pa[[i]]` you'll get gibberish. What you want is `Pa[p[[i]]]`.

Comment: Hi,  I tried that but get an error.

BinomialDistribution::probparm: Parameter {0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1} is expected to be a probability between 0 and 1. >

It does not seem to be able to extract one element of the vector.
CDF[BinomialDistribution[90,{0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1}],2]+ ...

Mary

Answer (score 1):

You've defined functions `Pa[p_]` and `ASN[p_]`, but I don't see where you've defined arrays that you can subscript as arrays. A lot of the definitions you're using here are misisng, so it's difficult to provide working code, but you might want to try

```
Print[TableForm[
  Table[{r2[[i]], p[[i]], Pa[i*0.1], ASN[i*0.1], Pa2[[i]], ASN2[[i]]}, {i,
    1, 10, 1}], 
   TableHeadings -> {None, {"roots", "p", "Pa[p]", "ASN[p]", "PA2[p]", 
     "ASN2[p]"}}]]
```

or something similar.